# Vue 2 call method in v-for performance issue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

Trying to figure out why the following code calls `someFunction()` 4 times instead of 1 time:

html:

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
    <input v-model="item.test">
    <div>{{ someFunction(item) }}</div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    test: 'test1',
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    test: 'testSomething',
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    test: 'foo',
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    test: 'bar',
                },
            ]
  },
  methods: {
    someFunction(item) {
       console.log(item.test);
       return item.test;
    },
  }
})
```

You can play with the code [here](https://codepen.io/BloodWork01/pen/zYNPqJp)

So my real world application has 30 items and a more complex `someFunction()`. At the moment, `someFunction()` is called once for every item as soon as only one item changes. But why is vue calling the function n times instead of only the one time needed?

EDIT: My problem are NOT the n function calls when the page is loaded. My problem are the n function calls when the input of only one input field is changed and thus only one function call is necessary, because all the other input values remain the same and thus the function result remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

By using v-model on nested item in "items" you are invoking global change on "items" variable, and by that the whole html is re-rendered because there was sensed change.
You want this re-render because v-model made some changes you want to keep displaying updated data.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I thought about this, however I wonder if I can tell Vue somehow 
 only to rerender the items that where changed and not just rerender everything, because one single item in a much bigger array has changed. I thought Vue might be smart enough to detect, that only one item has changed

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"> <------- 1.LOOP here
    <input v-model="item.test">
    <div>{{ someFunction(item) }}</div> <--------2.FUNCTION call here
  </div>
</div>
```

1. that means you go through each item in `items` array.
2. each iteration calls the method `someFunction(item)`

if you want a conditional executing you should `<div v-if="onlyIfIwant">{{ someFunction(item) }}</div>`     wrap it into a v-if to prevent the function call

---

### update

if you want conditional executes of the `someFunction()` then of course you have to add a flag in your objects like this:

```js
data: {
    items: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    test: 'test1',
                    execute: true
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    test: 'testSomething',
                    execute: false
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    test: 'foo',
                    execute: false
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    test: 'bar',
                    execute: true
                },
            ]
  },
```

your v-if just needs the following:

```html
<div v-if="item.execute">{{ someFunction(item) }}</div>
```

Comment: v-if will not fix the issue, because then it will not show the result of someFunction for each input. I understand, that when the page is loaded, 4 function calls are necessary. However, they are not, when I change the input value of only one item. Then there is only one function call necessary (the one for the changed value) but the other input fields where the value is kept the same are also called. Why is that?

Comment: @BloodWork01 ok well... a v-for will always rerender all of its content on each time a element in the  source array gets changed

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, it still is not quite the problem I have :) . When you use v-if, the functions result will not be rendered at all. What I want is that vue shows the functions result for every item in items. When a change is made to only one item (because I change something on the corresponding input field), vue should only call the function for that item again. But what vue actually does (and that is my problem) is to call someFunction(item) not only for the item that has changed, but also for all the items in the array that have not changed